# Definiteness of square of a positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

If $A$ is positive definite ,($\mathbf x^ \mathbf H A \mathbf x> 0$) then can we say that $A^2 $ is also positive definite?

Comment: is $A$ hermitian?

Comment: no it is not hermition

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is positive definite $\iff A$ is the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of linearly independent vectors. Suppose this representation is given by $A=V^HV$. Clearly $A^H=A$.
$$
A^2=A^HA\implies
x^HA^2x=x^HA^HAx=(Ax)^HAx=||Ax||^2\ge0
$$